# Java safe communication with database from multiple sessions

Tags: java, database, session, design-patterns, communication

I have to develop a small application for my company in Java which should show data from a database. The shown data should be editable in the gui and with a save button the edited data should be written to the database. 
My question is now how to handle the database communication because multiple users will use the application at the same time? I think there will be a problem if person A is watching the data and person B does a change. If now person A saves his change the data from person B is lost.

I couldn t find anything in the internet because i dont know which keyword i have to use for the search. I only could find something called dao pattern but i dont think thats the thing im looking for.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/archive.php?id=83

Comment: Data concurrency is the root issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is known as Database Locking;

> Locking is perhaps the most ignored persistence consideration. Most
>   applications tend to ignore thinking about concurrency issues during
>   development, and then smush in a locking mechanism before going into
>   production. Considering the large percentage of software projects that
>   fail or are canceled, or never achieve a large user base, perhaps this
>   is logical. However, locking and concurrency is a critical or at least
>   a very important issue for most applications, so probably should be
>   something considered earlier in the development cycle.
>
> If the application will have concurrent writers to the same objects,
>   then a locking strategy is critical so that data corruption can be
>   prevented. There are two strategies for preventing concurrent
>   modification of the same object/row; optimistic and pessimistic
>   locking. Technically there is a third strategy, ostrich locking, or no
>   locking, which means put your head in the sand and ignore the issue.
>
> **Optimistic Locking**
>
> Optimistic locking assumes that the data will not be modified between
>   when you read the data until you write the data. This is the most
>   common style of locking used and recommended in today's persistence
>   solutions. The strategy involves checking that one or more values from
>   the original object read, are still the same when updating it. This
>   verifies that the object has not changed by another user in between
>   the read and the write.
>
> **Pessimistic Locking**
>
> Pessimistic locking means acquiring a lock on the object before you
>   begin to edit the object, to ensure that no other users are editing
>   the object. Pessimistic locking is typically implemented through using
>   database row locks, such as through the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` SQL
>   syntax. The data is read and locked, the changes are made and the
>   transaction is committed, releasing the locks.

For more info and how to implement it in Java with `JPA` read [Java Persistence Locking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking)

Comment: Thanks Onur thats exactly what i am looking for.